# Jest Error: Failed to get mock metadata: node_modules/core-js/modules/$.global.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I'm useing Jest to test my React-App.
I have a handfull of test suites already, but I can not get 2 of them running.

One Error Example:

```
FAIL  react/utils/__tests__/ChartsUtils-tests.js (2.662s)

● ChartsUtils › it get labels for a date period
- Error: Failed to get mock metadata: /Users/nessie/Sites/blackriver-analytics-project/node_modules/core-js/modules/$.global.js
    at Loader._generateMock (node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:251:15)
    at Object.eval (node_modules/core-js/modules/$.export.js:1:137)
    at Object.eval (node_modules/core-js/modules/es5.js:3:25)
1 test failed, 0 tests passed (1 total in 1 test suite, run time 3.68s)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

My test looks like that:

```
/* global expect jest it beforeEach describe */
'use strict';

jest.dontMock('../ChartsUtils');

import ChartsUtils from '../ChartsUtils';

describe('ChartsUtils', function () {
    it('get labels for a date period', function () {
        // let labels = ChartsUtils.getLabels('2015-07-15', '2015-07-20');
        // console.log(labels)
    });
});
```

And my JS File like this:

```
'use strict'

import Period from 'date-period'
import Datetime from 'react-datetime'

module.exports = {
    getLabels: function (s, e) {
        let start = '',
            end = '',
            duration = 'P1D',
            period,
            days = []

        if (typeof s === 'number' && typeof e === 'number') {
            start = Datetime.moment.unix(s)
            end = Datetime.moment.unix(e)
        } else {
            start = Datetime.moment(s)
            end = Datetime.moment(e)
        }

        period = Period({start, duration, end})

        for (let date of period) {
            days.push(Datetime.moment(date).format('MMM, Do'))
        }

        return days
    }
};
```

Due to elimination of my code, I figured that the problem lies with

```
import Period from 'date-period'
```

But I already added the module to my **unmockedModulePathPatterns** in my package.json, which looks the following:

```
"jest": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "verbose": false,
    "noStackTrace": false,
    "collectCoverage": false,
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/react/jest/preprocessor.js",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-router",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-bootstrap",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-datetime",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/fbjs",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/events",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/object-assign",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/date-period",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/moment",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/keymirror"
    ],
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ]
},
```

I've been reading other bug reports and one suggested to change the path from /node_modules/date-period to just "date-period", but it didn't change anything for me.

My second file has the exact same error but with a different modul "react-bootstrap"